# How can I submit the form after clicking the save button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is some of my code from the file name `settings.handlebars`, the input box are disabled until Ii click the edit button. After adding a value in the input field it supposed to pass the value to my js if I click the save button. The code is below:

```
<form method="post" action="/save">
   <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" value="{{username}}">

   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="save" id="save">Save Changes</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" value="cancel" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="edit" id="edit">Edit Info</button>

</form>
```

This is my jQuery in the same file `settings.handlebars`.

```
<Script>
    $('#edit').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('#save, #cancel').show();
        $("#target :input").prop("disabled", false);
    });

    $('#cancel').click(function () {
        $('#edit').show();
        $('#save, #cancel').hide();
        $("#target :input").prop("disabled", true);
    });

    $('#save').click(function () {

        $(this).hide();
        $('#cancel').hide();
        $('#edit').show();
        $("#target :input").prop("disabled", true);

    });
    $("#target :input").prop("disabled", true);
</Script>
```

And this is my `main.js` file. When I click the save button this is supposed to work but nothing happens:

```
app.post('/save', function (req, res, next) {

    let configObj = {
        username: req.body.username
    }

    fs.writeFile('config.json', JSON.stringify(configObj), (err) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send("<h4>ERROR</h4>")
        }
    });
    res.redirect("/settings")
});
```

I think I missed something on my jQuery but I don't know what it is. Thank you!

Comment: Your `<Script>` tags have a capitol `S` in them..  I don't think that works..  Try changing them to all lowercase, ie: `<script>` and `</script>`.

Comment: @BryanElliott it actually works tho but i'll change it. but it's not submitting the form to my main.js can u help me with that pls

Comment: Is your node server running? First confirm it is running by putting a console.log inside your post request function..

Comment: @BryanElliott yes it is running

Comment: @BryanElliott do I need to insert something in my jQuery inside $('#save').click(function () to submit the form in my js?

Comment: Well, there is two ways to go about it, if you want to send an ajax request(without causing the page to reload) using jQuery, then yes.  Otherwise, you would just allow the form to take the default action when you press submit button, which will fire a request to your <form action.

Comment: If you want an ajax request,- In your `$('#save').click` function, add, `e.preventDefault();` and then `$.post( "http://localhost:3000/save", function( data ) {
  console.log(data);
});`  - something similar to that..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `e.preventDefault();` inside your `.click()`. It is currently preventing your form from submitting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `prevenDefault()` method cancels the event if it is cancelable, meaning that the default action that belongs to the event will not occur.

```
<script>
    // I have added only for the save function
    $('#save').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).hide();
        $('#cancel').hide();
        $('#edit').show();
        $("#target :input").prop("disabled", true);    
    });
    $("#target :input").prop("disabled", true);
</script>
```